# Stop NetLogo when it freezes

Tags: performance, netlogo

I am running a model on NetLogo but because I'm so new sometimes my procedures take FOREVER to load. After a certain amount of time I don't really care if the procedure works or not, I just need NetLogo to unfreeze and let me get back to the coding window. Is there a way to "cancel" a procedure while it's running (alternative to force closing the application)?

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I am aware, there is no interrupt available. If you're new though, you are presumably building small models, and NetLogo is very fast up to thousands of agents. Did you want to post the code that's giving you problems and maybe we can find what's causing the problem.

Comment: You may be able to use the `Halt` option (Tools > Halt) if the model is not too far gone- these freezes happened to me a lot when I was learning, and if I realized I'd made an error early enough I could stop the model. However, I would second Jen's point that there is likely a code problem that can be addressed and stop the hangs from happening at all.

Comment: Hey guys! Thank you both for your input. I am aware the way you can write code can be the issue but I am just loading a shapefile so the code isn't the problem. I am just using a very large shapefile to validate but sometimes the wait isn't worth it so I'd rather cancel loading it and move on. The halt option actually worked quite well and made the points all appear as soon as I clicked it so it was magical! Thanks again :)